# Why only one button?

Tags: reactjs

I make a request to my local server using `fetch()` method. The server returns this response:

```
{
    // total quantity elements in all page
    "total":7,
    // quantity elements in one page
    "perPage":3,
    // current page
    "page":1,
    // quantity page
    "lastPage":3,   
    // it category list. I display my category list on page.
    "data":[           
        {"id":1,"title":"animals","created_at":"/...","updated_at":"/..."},
        {"id":2,"title":"space","created_at":"/...","updated_at":"/..."},
        {"id":3,"title":"sport","created_at":"/...","updated_at":"/..."}
    ]
}
```

Also in my local server, I have ability to use query parameters `page` or `limit` which I insert in URL:

- `page` - using this param I can implement **pagination**
- `limit` - using this param I can implement **choose quantity element**

### I have two tasks:

1. <strike>Make **pagination**</strike> (DONE)
2. Make ability to **choose quantity** element on page using three buttons (**quantity three elements**, **quantity four elements**, **quantity five elements**)

First task I've already done, however the second task is where I have a problem.

Instead of three buttons, I have only one button. When I click this button in my page it displays two elements. I also need to show the other 2 buttons which will display three and four elements respectively when clicked.

See screenshot:
[image]

### What to fix in the code?

Maybe I wrote something wrong in the `return`?

I comment code **line** which implement **choose quantity element**

#### Home.js:

```
const Home = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    listCategory: [],     
    currentPage: 1,       
    buttonsPagination: 0,                    
    quantityElementPage: 3,                 // this line
    buttonsQuantityElementPage: 3           // this line
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData(currentPage, quantityElementPage) {   // this line
      try {
        const res = await apiCategory('api/categories', {
          method: 'GET',
        }, currentPage, quantityElementPage );                     // this line
          console.log(res);
        setValue({
          listCategory: res.data,       
          currentPage: res.page,               
          buttonsPagination: Math.ceil(res.total / res.perPage),
          quantityElementPage: res.perPage,                        // this line
        }); 
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    }
    fetchData(value.currentPage, value.quantityElementPage);         // this line
  }, [value.currentPage, value.quantityElementPage]);                // this line

  const changePage = (argPage) => {    
    setValue((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      currentPage: argPage,
    }));
  };

  const changeQuantityElementPage = (argElement) => {                // this method
    setValue((prev) => ({
      ...prev,
      quantityElementPage: argElement,
    }));
  };

  return (
    <div>

      <Table dataAttribute={value.listCategory} />

      {[...Array(value.buttonsPagination)].map((item, index) => (
      <button key={'listCategory' + index}   
              onClick={() => changePage(index + 1)}>{index + 1}
      </button>
      ))}

 //here I display button who choose quantity element:
  {[...Array(value.buttonsQuantityElementPage)].map((item, index) => (                  
      <button onClick={() => changeQuantityElementPage(index+2)}>quantity element - {index+2}
      </button>
      ))}

</div>
  );
};
```

#### apiCategory.js:

```
export const apiCategory = async (url, args, valuePage, valueElement) => { //add valueElement in argument
const getToken = localStorage.getItem('myToken');

  const response = await fetch(`${apiUrl}${url}?page=${valuePage}&limit=${valueElement}`, { //add valueElement in param limit
   ...args,
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8 ",
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${getToken}`,
      "Accept": 'application/json',
      ...args.headers,  
    },
  });

 return response.json();      
}
```

Comment: is `console.log(res);` gives expected output?

Comment: @Hagai Harari Now I see one button ```quantity element-2```. And when I click this button in my page display two elements, in console also two elements. But I need that will be also button who display three elements and four elements when user clicked but they are not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because your `value.buttonsQuantityElementPage` is undefined. When you call setValue in `useEffect`, you did not include the previous values. buttonsQuantityElementPage no longer exists on value.

Also, if the Array constructor `Array()` receives an undefined value, it will return an array with a single undefined value. i.e. `[...Array(undefinedValue)]` will yield `[undefined]`

There are two options for a fix.

Option 1. Update the setValue in your useEffect to include all previous values and then override the properties with new values.

```
setValue(prev => ({
    ...prev,
    listCategory: res.data,
    currentPage: res.page,
    buttonsPagination: Math.ceil(res.total / res.perPage),
    quantityElementPage: res.perPage,
}));
```

Option 2. Split out the `buttonsQuantityElementPage` into its own variable. As far as I can see in your code, `buttonsQuantityElementPage` does not change. If that is the case then use

```
const buttonsQuantityElementPage = 3
```

and in the return section

```
[...Array(buttonsQuantityElementPage)].map((item, index) => (
    <button onClick={() => changeQuantityElementPage(index + 2)}>quantity element - {index + 2}
    </button>
))
```

Comment: When I write like this:
http://i.piccy.info/i9/682bae1585e0cd5b75a48ed9da6b4460/1587844350/37875/1372209/1.png
I have error:
http://i.piccy.info/i9/bf4f9f14734547aea99f7cd94101b8df/1587844332/6050/1372209/2.png

Comment: can you include the line numbers in the image? I cannot see which line is line 73.

Comment: http://i.piccy.info/i9/23ca60bb4f22ef816c07d7d086473477/1587845316/66575/1372209/Screenshot_5.png

Comment: I put that same code into a codesandbox and did not receive that error. See https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-chatelet-7be9l?file=/src/App.js

Comment: thank you very much! Also this option work very well: ```{[...Array(value.buttonsQuantityElementPage)].map((item, index) => (                  
      <button onClick={() => changeQuantityElementPage(index+2)}>quantity element - {index+2}</button>))}``` I will try both options

Comment: Hello Joshua! I'm sorry to bother you again. But I still continue to make this application.Today I’ve been tormented all day for the implementation of a new small task and can’t make it( Please, if you have time, look at my new question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61448879/why-the-list-is-disappear-and-filtering-does-not-work

Comment: Hello Joshua! If you want help me, look at my new question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61528881/error-cannot-convert-undefined-or-null-to-object