# Why the list disappears and filtering does not work?

Tags: reactjs

I make a request to server and get data(category list) which I display in view table-list and implement some functional
And I have a task, what should I do with the list:

- **Make filtering by `title name` when user write name category in `input` and press button `Search`**

Filtering by title name I can implement using query params `q`, which I will insert into the file **apiCategory.js** when user wrote some category in input and press button submit
Example: `http://path/q=animals`. 
In this case on the page only category animals will be displayed.

But when I wrote the code that implements filtering by `title name` my list **disappear**. And **filtering don't work**.

### What to fix in the code?

Maybe I wrote something wrong in the method `filter` or `updateSearchInput`?

### Home.js:

```
const Home = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
    listCategory: [],
    filteredlistCategory: [],
    searchInput: ""
  });
   
  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData( searchInput ) {
        const res = await apiCategory('/pathApi', {
          method: 'GET',
        }, searchInput);
        
          setValue(prev => ({
            ...prev,
            listCategory: res.data,
         }));
    }
    fetchData(value.searchInput); 
  }, [value.searchInput]);


    const updateSearchInput = (e) => {
       setValue((prev) => ({
         searchInput: e.target.value
       }));
     };

    const filter = () => {
       setValue((prev) => 
          ({ searchInput, listCategory}) => ({
          filteredlistCategory: listCategory.filter(item =>
          item.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase()))
     }))
    };
  
  return (
    <div>
       <Search value={value.searchInput} onChange={updateSearchInput} onSearch={filter}/>  
       <Table dataAttribute={value.filteredlistCategory}/>
    </div>
  );
};
```

### apiCategory.js:

```
export const apiCategory = async (url, args, valueFilter) => {
  const response = await fetch(`${url}?q=${valueFilter}`, {   
   ...args,
    headers: {/....}
    }});

 return response.json();      
}
```

### Search.js:

```
export default ({ value, onChange, onSearch }) => {
  return (
    <div className="search">
        <input type="text" className="searchInput" onChange={onChange} value={value}/>
        <button className="buttonSearch" onClick={() => onSearch(value)}>Search</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

### Response from server:

```
{"data":[           
          {"id":1,"title":"animals","created_at":"/...","updated_at":"/..."},
          {"id":2,"title":"space","created_at":"/...","updated_at":"/..."},
          {"id":3,"title":"sport","created_at":"/...","updated_at":"/..."}
        ]
}
```

Comment: The problem is with the api response or the frontend code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see few issues with the code:

1. In your `fetchData` function you are not setting `filteredlistCategory`, but you are passing this list to `Table` components, so initially there would be no data displayed, as the list is empty.
2. In `updateSearchInput` you are not preserving old values (`listCategory` and `filteredlistCategory`). That's probably why list disappears. It should be more like this:

```
const updateSearchInput = (e) => {
    const searchInput = e.target.value;
    setValue((prev) => ({
        ...prev,
        searchInput: searchInput
    }));
};
```

3. Filter function is incorrect, it contains doubled function provided to `setValue`, you need to get rid one of them. Currently your are basically setting a function as a state value, which causes filtering to not work. Try something like this:

```
const filter = () => {
    setValue((prev) => ({
        ...prev
        filteredlistCategory: listCategory.filter(item =>
            item.firstName.toLowerCase().includes(searchInput.toLowerCase())
        )
    }))
};
```

However, in this case, for clarity of code, I would suggest to create separate states for each of those properties (3 `useState`s instead of just 1), so you don't need to remember preserving old values of others when changing only one of them. Alternatively, try using `useReducer` hook.

**EDIT:** I've done some changes to your Home.js file that should fix the issues:

- Before new request to the API was made on each character typed into search input - this is unefficient and I've changed it to only make request after `filter` button was clicked. It's done by removing dependency from `useEffect`, so it only runs once on initial component creation, and by making a request in `filter` function.
- Removed `filteredlistCategory` property as it doesn't seem to be necessary to store duplicated list inside this component (data is always fetched from server on new Search)

```
const Home = () => {
    const [value, setValue] = useState({
        listCategory: [],
        searchInput: ""
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData(value.searchInput);
    }, []);

    const fetchData = async ( searchInput ) => {
        const res = await apiCategory('/pathApi', {
            method: 'GET',
        }, searchInput);

        setValue(prev => ({
            ...prev,
            listCategory: res.data
        }));
    }

    const updateSearchInput = (e) => {
        const searchInput = e.target.value;
        setValue((prev) => ({
            ...prev,
            searchInput: searchInput
        }));
    };

    const filter = async () => {
        await fetchData(value.searchInput);
    };

    return (
      <div>
          <Search value={value.searchInput} onChange={updateSearchInput} onSearch={filter}/>
          <Table dataAttribute={value.listCategory}/>
      </div>
    );
};
```

Comment: I have error:
`Line 44:31:  'listCategory' is not defined  no-undef
Line 45:51:  'searchInput' is not defined   no-undef`
In method `filter`.

Comment: And what I need to change that fix you remark?:
`1. In your fetchData function you are not setting filteredlistCategory, but you are passing this list to Table components, so initially there would be no data displayed, as the list is empty.`
Please change my file Home.js and the corrected file code insert into your answer because I begginer and I do not understand everything

Comment: error :http://i.piccy.info/i9/1c7ef7f81ba0b93b8c79de737a97cf3c/1587976960/39999/1372209/Screenshot_1.png

Comment: It looks like your `res.data` is `undefined`, instead of some array - check API response.