# Error: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I make request to the server using `fetch` and get response - category list. This list I display in view- table. Near each category on the right I have button **Delete**. When I click this button appears modal window with two buttons `Delete` and `Cancel`. I used API method `DELETE` that delete some category.

When I click button `Delete` in modal window

#### My category delete! It's good!

But in my page appears error:

### TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Why is this happening? And how to fix it?

### In my opinion, that this error is maybe occurring because I incorrectly write method `deleteCategory`

### Home.js:

```
const Home = () => {
    
  const [value, setValue] = useState({
     /.....
    listCategory: [],
    numberIdDelete: "",
    isOpenedDelete: false
  });
    
const deleteCategory = (argDeleteCategory) => {    //  in this method id some category set as value in field - numberIdDelete                                   
    setValue({                                     //  that is, I'll know on which category the user has clicked delete button
        ...value,
        numberIdDelete: argDeleteCategory,     //  this id I put in path in component DeleteCategory
        isOpenedDelete: true
    });
};
    
const cancel = () => {                   // close modal window
    setValue({
        ...value,
        isOpenedDelete: false
    });
};
    
  return (
    <div> 
      <Table dataAttribute={value.listCategory} 
             deleteCategory={deleteCategory}/>    // in component Table located button Delete
                 
         {value.isOpenedDelete && <DeleteCategory value={value.numberIdDelete} cancel={cancel} />} 
   </div>
  );
};
```

### DeleteCategory.js:

```
const DeleteCategory = (props) => {
    
    const {handleSubmit} = useFormik({  
        onSubmit: async () => {
              const response = await fetch(`pathToServer/${props.value}`, { // put value from state (id some category)
                  method:'DELETE',
                  headers: {/.....}
              });
              const data = await response.json();   
      }});

   return ( 
     <div >
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}> 
          <button type="submit" onClick={() => props.delCategory}>Delete</button>
          <button type="submit" onClick={() => props.cancel}>Cancel</button>
      </form>
    </div>
   );
};
```

### Table.js:

```
export default (props) => (
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>ID</th>  
        <th>TITLE</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
       {props.dataAttribute.map(item => (
        <tr key={item.id}>
          <td>{item.id} </td>
          <td>{item.title} </td>
          <td><button onClick={() => props.deleteCategory(item.id)}>Delete</button></td>    // Button Delete
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
);
```

Comment: Where is your error produced? Do you have the stack trace?

Comment: http://i.piccy.info/i9/64ec1f9ce9b1ba48036af879621070a6/1588269706/60953/1372209/aaa.png
and http://i.piccy.info/i9/0025ce94d82d6e6a3e38259954a6eaee/1588269768/25205/1372209/bbb.png
But I dont have this code in my app. These are some kind of inside js,react or formik. I don't think you should pay attention to them. I think it problem that I incorectly wrote method deleteCategory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the way you are calling `useFormik`. The way you are configuring it, there are no input fields associated with it.

This causes that when you click the delete button a submit is performed and `useFormik` tries to build an object with the input values to pass it to `onSubmit` prop. But there are no inputs.

Examining your `DeleteCategory` component code, you don't need to use `useFormik`. You are only showing a confirmation modal after all. Instead, you could do something like:

```
const DeleteCategory = (props) => {
    const delCategory = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(`pathToServer/${props.value}`, { // put value from state (id some category)
            method:'DELETE',
            headers: {/.....}
        });
        const data = await response.json();

        // Do whatever when your request has been performed.
    };

   return ( 
       <div >
          <button type="button" onClick={() => delCategory()}>Delete</button>
          <button type="button" onClick={props.cancel}>Cancel</button>
       </div>
   );
};
```

Comment: Why you wrote:
`<button type="button" onClick={() => delCategory()}>Delete</button>
          <button type="button" onClick={props.cancel}>Cancel</button>`
------------------------- instead: 
`<button type="submit" onClick={() => props.delCategory}>Delete</button>
          <button type="submit" onClick={() => props.cancel}>Cancel</button>`
?

Comment: Why do you need a submit button if you don't have a form? You can check the specification of button types in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button).

Comment: Simply I get error in console from local server:
`DeleteCategory.js:15 DELETE http://localhost:3333/api/categories/6 500 (Internal Server Error)`
But category delete good

Comment: You should check your server controller then, as a 500 code means an Internal Server Error. Most probably, you have an error in your server-side code.

Comment: ok, Now when I click delete my list is not updated. He update only when I update browser. How update list after I click button delete?